# Find numbers such that...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all the triples $(x,y,z)∈Z^3$ such that

$x^2+7y^2=2012z^2.$

It is clear that $7y^2 \equiv 0$(mod 7), so $x^2\equiv3z^2$(mod 7).
I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: $x^2\equiv0,1,2,$ or $4\pmod7$; $3z^2\equiv0, 3, 5, $ or $6\pmod7$; $(0,0,0)$ is a solution

Comment: I get that x,y and z are multiples of 7, what can I get from that?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $n^2\equiv 0,1,2,4 \bmod 7$, so $3n^2 \equiv 0,3,5,6 \bmod 7$

What does this tell you about $x,z \bmod 7$?

And what does that tell you about how many factors of $7$ are in each of $x,y,z$?

Comment: So, finally we get that x,y and z are multiples of 7.

Comment: And then what? :(

Comment: If $x,y,z$ are multiples of $7$, then $x^2$ and $z^2$ have an even number of factors of $7$, but $7y^2$ has an odd number of factors of $7$.

Comment: And is that enough to say that the only solution is trivial?

Comment: By infinite descent?

Comment: Yes, by infinite descent.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-One has the following

**Theorem** (Diophantine Equations, L. J. Mordell).- If $a,b,c$ are square free positive integers, $(a,b)=(b,c)=(c,a)=1$ then the equation $ax^2+by^2=cz^2$ has non-trivial integer solutions if and only if $bc,ac,-ab$ are quadratic residues of $a,b,c$ respectively and $ax^2+by^2=cz^2\equiv 0\pmod8$.

Applying this result to the equation $x^2+7y^2=2012z^2$ we have in particular that the equation $t^2\equiv2012\pmod7\iff t^2\equiv3\pmod7$ has no solution (it is easily verified that $3$ is not square modulo $7$.

Consequently the only solution is the trivial one, $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the  solution for $y$ below

\begin{align*}
x^2+7y^2&   =2012z^2\\ 
\implies 7y^2&=2012z^2-x^2\\
\implies y&=\sqrt{\frac{2012z^2-x^2}{7}}
\end{align*}

the only fractions that yield intgers are when $x,z$ are both mutiples of $7.\quad$ Of those integers none are perfect squares for $x,z,\le 7000\quad$
This is not proof but it is strong evidence that the only solution is $\quad(0,0,0)$